# Looking for a short story, aliens (or demons) are effectively dumb animals that reproduce by implanting eggs in human mouths

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens

It's part of a collection of stories, I think.  A woman answers her door and sticks her tongue out at the alien, which causes it to smile.  For some reason, the aliens aren't deadly unless a victim's mouth is open.  The woman realizes that the alien is well endowed and has sex with it, believing she is in control. It turns out it's an evolved form of the alien and it tricked her.